# MySQL enter information into table from user input

Tags: php, mysql

On my website I have a PHP script which (when user enters a "username" and "password" into a form) checks a MySQL table for the existence of the username and password, and passes the user onto the main page of the website. Here is my question: **Is there a way to add rows into the table when a user inputs information into a form?** Below is the php page described above. Is there a way to modify this script to allow a user to input rows?

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="--------"; // Host name 
$username="-------"; // Mysql username 
$password="--------"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="--------"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="-------"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) ???

Comment: To Cfreak: I have only tried to connect to the server and select the database like above (which I would assume would be the first step) but I do not know of a PHP tag to insert a row into a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a MySQL Insert statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, password) values ('$myusername', '$mypassword')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Feida's answer above is generally correct, but be forewarned that you SHOULD NOT DO THIS before learning more about basic Web security -- particularly the subject of "sanitizing user input." There are way too many things a user could enter that might ruin your (or anyone else's on your server) day unless you really understand this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your code there has multiple issues :

- you are still using the ancient `mysql_*` function. Instead you should look into learning how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) ( or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli), if you believe that MySQL is only relavent RDBMS ) and read about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).
- you should **never** store passwords in plain-text form. It is a huge security risk. You can even use [`crypt()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function in PHP to do it.
- isn't you username already a `UNIQUE` field in that table ? Why are you adding additional condition with password ? Instead you should select the hashed password from table, and, if there was an entry for you user, chech this stored hash against hashed version of password from `$_POST`

Anyway , none of this code you have provided in "question" contains anything for *allowing a user to input rows*. **StackOverflow is a Q/A site, not a free code generator.**

Comment: Alright, Thank you for your response. It is definitely helpful and I'll keep your comment in mind when making future posts. Thanks!!